# CSS transform: scale(0.001) works but scale(0.0) doesn't

Tags: html, css

I'm making a website and have a shapes that do CSS transitions. On the transition that I'm currently working on something strange happens. If I put transform: scale(0.001) the transition works as intended happening over a one second period, but if I put scale(0.0) the element just disappears with no animation. Tested in Chrome btw.

Why is this happening? Why doesn't scale(0.0) work? Thanks for the help.

Relevant CSS class below

```
.blue.centred {  
    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1.0s, 1.0s;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.0s, 0.0s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    -moz-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
    -moz-transition-duration: 1.0s , 1.0s;
    -moz-transition-delay: 0.0s, 0.0s;
    -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    -ms-transformtransition-property: -webkit-transform;
    -ms-transformtransition-duration: 1.0s, 1.0s;
    -ms-transformtransition-delay: 0.0s, 0.0s;
    -ms-transformtransition-timing-function: ease-out;
    transition-property:  transform;
    transition-duration: 1.0s, 1.0s;
    transition-delay: 0.0s, 0.0s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    transform: rotate(-180deg) scale(0.001);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but there isn't enough information here to reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I see no problem with scale(0.0).  I changed your code to remove the vendor prefixes, and the double properties for transition even though there was only one, and use :hover as the transition target.  Hover over "text" to trigger the transition.

```css
h1 {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1.0);
}

h1:hover {
  transition-property: transform;
  transition-duration: 1s;
  transition-delay: 0.0s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transform: rotate(-180deg) scale(0.0);
}
```

```html
above
<h1 class="blue centred">text</h1>
below
```

Comment: also, you just need one zero :)

Comment: Hovering over the center of the `h1` leads to the best experience :).